# Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate can't create VC++ projects anymore

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

All of a sudden, Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate fails to create VC++ projects, running Windows 7.

For example, when iI go to New -> Project -> Visual C++ -> Win32 -> Win32 Console application, and go through the wizard I get an error message:

**name must not be empty**

**Parameter name: name**

I've tried reinstalling VS2010 several times, but I can't get it to work. There are no problems when creating, say, Visual C# projects.

I really need some help here. Googling the issue seems to point at permission errors, but I can't get it to work with any of the solutions I found.

**EDIT**

I solved this. The process monitor tool is excellent for debugging problems such as this. I fired it up and monitored **degenv**.

Apparently, VS2010 seems to have saved find queries for which I used the option "Look in files..". Those files were long ago deleted, and I saw errors relating to old C#-files in which I've used the "Look in files.." option. I checked the Find-dropdown and searched the registry for one of the queries, and deleted all the Find* and Replace* keys that came up.

So, go to **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Find** and remove the keys **Find**, **Find1**, etc and **Replace**, **Replace1** etc.

Now I can create VC++ projects without going into safe-mode. I'm leaving my solution here if anyone else has similar problems.

**EDIT2**

Scratch that. Now I broke something again, and I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: I've tried running VS2010 in safe-mode, **degenv /Safemode**, which makes project creation work. However, trying to open the same project when not in safe-mode doesn't work.