# VC++ 2010 does not create C++ projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have a really big problem. Visual studio 2010 does not create C++ projects any more. When I click to create a new C++ project (no matter console or Win32) it shows the next dialog, which should allow me to choose project settings, but I cannot do anything in this dialog (when I click Cancel or Finish nothing happens, I can just close this window), also, this dialog does not show all settings, like it had. 
Non-C++ project are being created successfully. 
I've installed a VC++ express, but it has the same problem. Class creation window also has this problem.

I tryed to reinstall VS, but it had no effect.
I tryed to launch from VS console devenv.exe /setup and devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates
I tryed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074803/visual-studio-2010-ultimate-cant-create-vc-projects-anymore)

This is a screeshot of project creation dialog (labels are in russian, but you can open this window in your VS to see the difference) [image: window screen]

**UPD:** translated window:
[image]

**UPD:**
Skype main window has a problem - it does not display any contensts. It seems, that problem is in IE

Comment: Please post a translation of the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these wizard pages use HTML and javascript and are displayed by an embedded WebBrowser.

Your IE install is messed up.

Comment: Yes, problem was in IE. I've just reinstalled it and problem was solved